# Using Values in dictionary to groupby and average

Tags: python, dictionary, average

```
new_list_df = list(map(lambda x : list(range(x[0], x[1]+1)), df_test[['StartMonth','EndMonth']].values))

display(new_list_df)
```

output:

[[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

```
my_dict = dict(zip(cheat_list, new_list_df))
print(my_dict)
```

Output:
{'2019PeakWE': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}

I would like to use mydict output and average all of the months on the value part of the key. Is that possible? The months and values I would like it to display is in the link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By dict comprehension you can do

```py
example = {"2019PeakWE": [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], "tutu": [1, 3]}

averages = {key: sum(example[key]) / len(example[key]) for key in example}
print(averages)
```